# Converting date timestamp from 12 hour into 24 using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, mawk

I am working with a csv file which contains data in the following structure:

```
"12345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333,"15/12/2017 4:26:00 PM"
```

I want to convert the 12 hour time into 24 hour time.
The following shows what I am trying to achieve in the end:

```
"12345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333,"15/12/2017 16:26:00"
```

I found the following answer to a question which seems to solve the conversion of the time segment of my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083973/bash-and-awk-converting-a-field-from-12-hour-to-24-hour-clock-time#8084087

So with the above, I believe I must do the following process (There is probably a more efficient method):

1. Temporarily separate the date and time into there own records

   "12345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333,"15/12/2017","4:26:00 PM"
2. Target the time record and convert it into my desired 24 hour format
3. Concatenate the date and time records back into a single record

I am trying to achieve this using awk and am stuck on the first section! Is awk to right tool for this job, or would you recommend a different tool?

I'm starting with step 1. I can't even successfully target the date!

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} { gsub(/[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{4\}/, "TESTING"); print }' myfile.csv
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `perl` here:

```
perl -pe 's{\b(\d{1,2})(:\d\d:\d\d) ([AP])M\b}{
  $1 + 12 * (($3 eq "P") - ($1 == 12)) . $2}ge'
```

That is add 12 to the hour part if PM (except for 12PM) and change 12AM to 0.

With `awk`, not doing the word-boundary part (so could give false positives on `123:21:99 AMERICA` for instance) and assuming there's only one occurrence per line:

```
awk '
  match($0, /[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M/) {
    split(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH), parts, /[: ]/)
    if (parts[4] == "PM" && parts[1] != 12) parts[1] += 12
    if (parts[4] == "AM" && parts[1] == 12) parts[1] = 0

    $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1) \
         parts[1] ":" parts[2] ":" parts[3] \
         substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
  }
  {print}'
```

Comment: The OP should be made aware that you are using the GNU extensions to `awk`, ie `gawk`, which might not be available on his/her system. Also, you can make small efficiency gains by replacing `$0` with `$NF`, since we know we are dealing with the final field of every line.  Finally, instead of having the address range checking for a complicated regex `match` including `[AP]M` for **every** line, and later checking again for PM, just have the address range `/PM\"$/`, put the `match` command inside the braces with PM only, and then you can  remove the `if` clause.

Comment: @user1404316 What GNU extension? As far as I know, that code is POSIX.

Comment: @user1404316 we still need to get rid of the AMs

Comment: My `man` page reads: "String Functions ... Gawk has the following built-in string functions: ... match( ..." BTW, I can't seem to be able to '@' you - is there a trick to it, maybe because of the
'é' in your name or something?

Comment: @user1404316 there's nothing in the OP's question that says the date is always in the last field.

Comment: @user1404316 match () is standard

Comment: Correct point about getting rid of the AMs, so make the address range /[AP]M\"$/, which matches the structure he supplied in his question, with the time as the final field of every line.

Comment: @user1404316, sounds like you have some idea about how to implement a solution that works when making different assumptions about the format of the OP's input (which is not clearly specified). Why don't you post your own answer?

Comment: No need to "@" the author of the post you're replying to. The author of the post is always notified. That's why SE doesn't offer it to you as a possible completion.

Comment: @GustavMahler, the solution was wrong for 12:00 am/pm. See edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I searched information about your correction and found [this](https://greenwichmeantime.com/info/noon/). Quote: " This means that 00:00 A.M. or 00:00 P.M. (or 12:00 A.M. and 12:00 P.M.) have no meaning. Every day starts precisely at midnight and A.M. starts immediately after that point in time e.g. 00:00:01 A.M.".

Comment: @MinMax, my correction is based on the output of `date +%r` in a British locale. Which use 12:00 am .. 12:59am 1:00am .. 11:59am 12:00pm..12:59pm 1:00pm .. 11:59pm for 00:00 .. 23:59. I think that's the most common way these days.

Answer (score 0):

This solution converts all items of the 12-hour format to the 24-hour format in each line.

```
gawk -F, '
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if($i ~ /:[0-9]{2} [PA]M/) {
            split($i, arr, ":| ")

            if(arr[5] ~ /P/)
                arr[2] += 12 

            $i = sprintf("%s %02d:%02d:%02d\"", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4])
        }
    }
    print
}' OFS=, input.txt
```

**Input**

```
"12345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","15/12/2017 4:26:00 PM"
"22345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","16/12/2017 6:26:00 AM"
"32345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","17/12/2017 10:00:00 PM"
"42345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","18/12/2017 11:26:00 AM"
"52345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","19/12/2017 2:26:00 PM"
```

**Output**

```
"12345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","15/12/2017 16:26:00"
"22345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","16/12/2017 06:26:00"
"32345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","17/12/2017 22:00:00"
"42345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","18/12/2017 11:26:00"
"52345","BLAH","DEDA","0.000","1.111","2.22222","3.3333333","19/12/2017 14:26:00"
```